# How to pause program execution for some time?

Tags: red

I'm using "Red Programming Language" version "0.6.4" on Windows and making a command line application.

I don't know much Red language and I don't understand many things. I did go over "work in progress" docs at (https://doc.red-lang.org/en/) before asking here.

I need to see the "Something, something..." on the screen for a bit (let's say 1 second) before the command prompt window closes.

```
Red []

; do something
print "Something, something..."

; pause 1 // not working
; sleep 1 // not working

quit
```

As in the code comments I've tried with `pause` or `sleep` but I get an error `Script Error: sleep has no value`. How to make it sleep?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you are looking for is WAIT. Try `wait 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`WAIT`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/wait.html) as prescribed by @MarkI above is the correct answer.

But I wanted to add below which should really be a comment but it looks nicer formatted!

The best way to explore Red/Rebol is via the console and making use of [`HELP`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/help.html)

```
>> help pause
No matching values were found in the global context.
```

This means there is nothing defined for PAUSE (and ditto for `help sleep`).

So instead quote the word and it will search through all defined function documentation...

```
>> help "sleep"
No matching values were found in the global context.

>> help "pause"
No matching values were found in the global context.
```

Still no luck :(

OK lets try something related...

```
>> help "time"
... long list found items...
```

This now returns all functions that have some connection to "time" in their function spec/docs.  In this list is `WAIT` function.   However another HELP clearly shows it...

```
>> help "duration"
     wait            native!       Waits for a duration in seconds or specified time.
```

Now we have it...

```
>> help wait
USAGE:
     WAIT value

DESCRIPTION:
     Waits for a duration in seconds or specified time.
     WAIT is a native! value.

ARGUMENTS:
     value        [number! time! block! none!]

REFINEMENTS:
     /all         => Returns all events in a block
```

Hope that helps.